# Error al agregar `NOT IN` en una consulta de sentencias preparadas

Tags: php, mysqli

Al añadir `NOT IN` en una consulta:

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT producto,detalle 
                            FROM producto 
                            WHERE activo=? NOT IN ($producto) 
                            order by id_producto ASC limit 10");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$activo);
$activo = "1";
```

Me imprime el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\productos.php on line 9

La linea del error corresponde a la siguiente linea

```
$stmt->bind_param("i",$activo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes tener muy en cuenta que estas aplicando sentencias preparadas.

Por lo tanto debes agregar en la consulta o bien variable directas `$` o el símbolo `?` en la consulta.

Por lo tanto la consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT producto,detalle 
                            FROM producto 
                            WHERE activo=? NOT IN (?) 
                            order by id_producto ASC limit 10");
$stmt->bind_param("ii",$activo,$producto);
$activo = "1";
```

En el `bind_param` debes agregar lo siguiente:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ii",$activo,$producto);
```

Como indicas que la variable `$producto` es el `id` de un producto se le agregga el valor `i` si fuera texto le agregas el valor de `s`.

Comment: Gracias :) tendré muy en cuenta esos pequeños detalles de suma importancia.

Answer (score 0):

Tu sentencia esta mal construida.  Creo que necesitas dos condiciones separadas.  Algo asi:

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT producto,detalle 
                        FROM producto 
                        WHERE activo=? AND activo NOT IN ($producto) 
                        order by id_producto ASC limit 10");
```

Comment: Me sigue mostrando el mismo error amigo

Comment: Que es lo que tienes en la variable `$producto`?

Comment: es el id del producto, si estoy viendo el detalle del mismo producto lo que trato es de no volver a mostrar ese mismo producto en los productos relacionados

Comment: Entonces que es lo que contiene la variable `$activo`?  Quizas deberias poner mas codigo para ver el contexto.

Comment: en el código publicado en mi pregunta está amigo que valor tiene, tiene el valor 1.

Comment: creo que deberias poner la estructura de la tabla producto, asi podemos ser algo mas preciso...

Comment: @alanfcm la nueva [respuesta de @IniDesing.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/181796/error-al-agregar-not-in-en-una-consulta-de-sentencias-preparadas/181821#181821) soluciono mi problema, gracias por el tiempo dedicado.

Answer (score 0):

Como apunta @alanfcm, esta mal construida, pero aparte de eso la variable $producto podria estar mal formada, si nos dices que es lo que contiene ayudaria.

Por otra parte parece que esto:

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT producto,detalle 
                        FROM producto 
                        WHERE activo=? NOT IN ($producto) 
                        order by id_producto ASC limit 10");
```

esta devolviendo un valor booleano por que despues al hacer

```
$stmt->bind_param("i",$activo);
```

The da el error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in ...
```

Lo que me hace pensar que el $conexion->prepare falla y de devuelva false o que igual devuelve true como estado y deberias de ejecutar la siguente linea.

```
$conexion->bind_param("i",$activo);
```

Si nos imprime que contiene el valir $stmt nos ayudaria a saber mas.

Comment: Lo que estoy haciendo es evitar mostrar el mismo producto que estoy viendo en el detalle del mismo, en la lista de productos relacionados.

Comment: si quito el `NOT IN` funciona los resultados, pero hacerlo de esa manera me mostrara el producto que ya estoy viendo en la lista de productos relacionados.

Comment: Podrias hacer un print $producto antes del prepare y un print $stmt despues del prepare para ver que tienen ?

Answer (score 0):

indagando un poco y con lo poco o mucho que nos muestras, llego a la conclusion que estas haciendo mal uso de `NOT IN` ya que estas comparando el parametro de entrada con un con el.

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT producto,detalle 
                        FROM producto 
                        WHERE activo=? AND id_producto NOT IN ($producto) 
                        order by id_producto ASC limit 10");
```

mira asi y nos cuentas

espero te sirva

Comment: la nueva [respuesta de @IniDesing.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/181796/error-al-agregar-not-in-en-una-consulta-de-sentencias-preparadas/181821#181821) soluciono mi problema, gracias por el tiempo dedicado.

Comment: excelente, el tiene mucha razon